# Bad request when attempting to filter by alias

Tags: urbanairship.com

```
{
  "notification": {
    "alert": "Rich Broadcast"
  },
 "message": {
    "title": "Rich Title",
    "body": "<html>The Body</html>",
    "content_type": "text/html"
  },
  "audience": "all",
  "device_types": "all"
}
```

Works fine, but when I attempt to filter by alias I get a bad request:

```
{
  "notification": {
    "alert": "Just one"
  },
  "message": {
    "title": "The title, device registered to 1234567890 only",
    "body": "<html>The body</html>",
    "content_type": "text/html"
  },
  "audience": {
    "alias": "01b307acba4f54f55aafc33bb06bbbf6ca803e9a"
  },
  "device_types": "all"
}
```

Gives a bad request:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Can anyone post some json that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API will respond with a 400 if you are sending a rich push but you don't limit the device_types to platforms that are compatible with rich push. These incompatible platforms include wns, mpns, and blackberry.

```
{
  "notification": {
    "alert": "Just one"
  },
  "message": {
    "title": "The title, device registered to 1234567890 only",
    "body": "<html>The body</html>",
    "content_type": "text/html"
  },
  "audience": {
    "alias": "01b307acba4f54f55aafc33bb06bbbf6ca803e9a"
  },
  "device_types": ["ios","android"]
}
```